# Bash timeout with group command and openssl

Tags: bash, openssl

I am trying to determine if a particular website uses ssl (https mode) or not.
So the below bash code has a url which is passed on to the openssl tool and the output is sent of to the text file. However the command fails  with *syntax error: unexpected end of file*

```
timeout 1m bash -c --  '{ openssl s_client -connect mywebsite.com:443 -bugs -brief |& tee website.txt }'
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you make a one-line compound statement, you need a semi-colon (and a space) at the end `{ statement; statement; }`. Though I am not sure why you have a compound statement in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduce your error like this:

```
bash -c --  '{ echo hello | cat }'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The solution is to remove the curly brackets:

```
bash -c --  'echo hello | cat'
hello
```